# Cocos2d-x Build for iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I am playing around with cocos2d-x trying to get the example to build but I keep getting an error `"Cannot recognize the target platform; are you targeting an unsupported platform?"` below is the ifdef statement for the iPhone target. But it doesn't seem to be picking up the iOS Simulator.

```
#if defined(CC_TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
    #undef  CC_TARGET_PLATFORM
    #define CC_TARGET_PLATFORM         CC_PLATFORM_IOS
#endif
```

Is there something I need to change to get it to work on iOS Simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project C++ settings you should add define `CC_TARGET_OS_IPHONE`

Answer (score 2):

Go to file **CCPlatformConfig.h** in `cocos2dx/platform` folder. Change the line,

```
// Determine target platform by compile environment macro.
#define CC_TARGET_PLATFORM             CC_PLATFORM_UNKNOWN
```

to the targeted platform. In your case it is iOS.

```
#define CC_TARGET_PLATFORM             CC_PLATFORM_IOS
```